# What are the differences between each novel version of Ousama Game?

Tags: ousama-game

I was looking at collecting the novels for *Ousama Game*. I ended up getting all of the published novels. However, when I was looking at the [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8E%8B%E6%A7%98%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0_(%E5%B0%8F%E8%AA%AC)#%E3%80%8E%E7%8E%8B%E6%A7%98%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%80%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%91%BD%E4%BB%A4), I found a few things I couldn't find.

It says something about the original online version having differences, an extra edition, and eVista first edition. I did find the novels on the website [estar.jp](https://estar.jp/publish/osamagame_lp/) but I was unsure if those were just the published volumes or original web version.

So I was wondering if anyone knew what the differences were between the different versions, and where to find them?

Comment: Just a clarification on the term: by eVista, did you mean エブリスタ版? From estar.jp, it seems エブリスタ actually means ["Everystar"](https://estar.jp/gp/), which refers to the online novel site itself.

Comment: I think that was it. I had to use a online translator for the site, so some things probably weren't fully correct. I'm pretty sure that part was referring to something separate from the online version though. From what I gathered there was the printed volumes, a special extra edition volume, the online, then the one thing. I could be wrong though.